LayoutParams weight works unexpectedly
I'm trying to create LinearLayout with 2 children LinearLayouts. I can't use XML and should make this programmatically.
For parent I apply:
LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT, 1f)

1st child:
LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT, 0.3f)

2nd child:
LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT, 0.7f)

I expected child 2 to be bigger than child 1, but they're inverted. Child 1 takes more space than child 2.
Why I get this behaviour and how to fix it?

If you want a percentage based layout like that, the width of the children must be 0.  Not MATCH_PARENT or WRAP_CONTENT (assuming a horizontal layout.  If vertical, the same rule applies but for height).  Weight is ignored if the width is non-zero
